# How to make a file whose name contains every printable character in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a slightly odd problem. On the nfs filesystem I am mounting it seems to translate all hyphens into colons. For example "a-b" becomes "a:b" and "a--b" becomes "a::b".  I would like to test what else it translates.

One way is to make a file whose name contains every ASCII printable character and see what it becomes. How can one do this in bash?

Comment: You might want to try non-printable characters as well. The only characters *not* allowed in a path component are the null character (ASCII 0) and `/` (since that is the character used to separate directories from other directories/files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt at a pure Bash solution:

```
filename=
for (( charnum=1 ; charnum<256 ; charnum++ )) ; do
    printf -v char_oct_esc '%03o' "$charnum"
    printf -v char "\\$char_oct_esc"
    [[ $char != / && $char =~ [[:print:]] ]] && filename+=$char
done

echo >"$filename" \
    && printf 'Created <<%s>>\n' "$filename" \
    || printf 'Failed to create <<$filename>>\n' "$filename"
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071 for excellent information about converting between characters and numbers in Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -e '$name = join "", grep !m{/}, map chr, 32 .. 126; open my $F, ">", $name or die $!'
```

I omitted the `/`.

Comment: Interestingly, exactly as you had written it originally (with the /) it didn't create a file at all as far as I can tell. Either that or it puts it somewhere surprising.

Comment: @user2179021: It failed silently because the subdirectory doesn't exist. Now it fails with a message if there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`man ascii > all_ascii_chars.txt`

Comment: I am trying to make a file whose name is every printable ASCII character. This doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Yes, well you may want to edit your question to reflect that, then

Answer (score 0):

With perl:

```
sub isPrint {
    my $c = shift;
    return $c =~ /\P{IsC}/
}

my $i; 
for ($i=0; $i<128; $i++) {
    if(isPrint(chr($i))) {
        print chr($i);
    }   
}
```

Outputs:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~t
```

Comment: Thank you but in my case I really want to make a file with that file name and I need to execute this from the command line.

Comment: Yes, of course. Save it in a file `test.pl` and execute it via command line `perl test.pl`